# Como executar uma função Javascript logo após carregar o DOM usando React Hooks?

Tags: react, react-hooks

Preciso criar diversas tags li baseadas em um array e então inseri-las em uma div, entretanto preciso esperar a tal div ser criada antes de realizar tal feito. Já que no React não existe o DOMContentLoaded o que posso usar para fazer o mesmo efeito? Estou trabalhamdo com React Hooks

Comment: Não entendi muito bem você tem o exemplo do código em `React`?

Comment: Deu certo a minha resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que pude entender, é necessário a execução de alguma função quando o componente estiver pronto (*carregado*), utilize [useEffect](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) com um `array` sem nenhuma posição, isso significa a execução após o carregamento do componente, exemplo:

```js
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([
    {id: 1, name: 'name 1'},{id: 2, name: 'name 2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'name 3'},{id: 4, name: 'name 4'}
  ]);
  function init() {
    console.log('carregou ...');
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    init();
  },[]);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {list && list.map((l,x) => (<li key={x}>{l.name}</li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo, eu posso usar isso atrelado a uma div? Assim que uma div for renderizada o useEffect chamar uma função?

Comment: Você pode fazer sim @JhonatasFlordeSousa precisa exemplificar como você quer isso, abra outra pergunta e explique tudo isso de maneira mais clara possível porque, cada duvida gera um nova pergunta